# Unable to remove a key value pair from JSON string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

On doing `console.log(data.toString())`, I get the following output:

```
{
      "cid":"9333227",
      "status" : 30,
      "user" : "user1"
}
```

On doing `console.log(data['cid'])` before performing delete, I get `undefined` as the output

I want to remove the `cid` key value pair such that the `console.log(data.toString())` should generate the following output:

```
{
      "status" : 30,
      "user" : "user1"
}
```

I am doing `delete data['cid']` and then doing `console.log(data.toString())`. However, it is still printing the original json

```
{
      "cid":"9333227",
      "status" : 30,
      "user" : "user1"
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a delete operator on a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `data.toString())`, and get the output you got, means that `data` is not an object. It's likely a string.

If you run:

```
"hello".toString();
```

you get "hello".

If you run:

```
delete "hello".foo
```

You are deleting a non-existant property on the string, which works without error. It doesn't change the contents of the string.

So I think you don't have an object, you have a JSON string. To mutate it, you need to first parse it:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(data);
delete obj.cid;
console.log(obj);
```

If you need to turn it back into a JSON string, you can use `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let jsonobj = {
  "cid": "933227",
  "status": 30,
  "user": "user1",
}

delete jsonobj['cid']

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonobj));
```

Try JSON.stringify() instead of .toString()